# Equivalent of getElementById for Classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm currently making a game, and I'm trying to change the CSS values of a whole class of objects. For a single ID, I would use, `document.getElementById("idHere")`, but I need something like `document.getElementByClass("classHere")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is simply `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")`, which returns an array of all the elements with that HTML class.

If you're using jQuery, you can do it with `$(".myClass")`, which will return a collection of all of the elements with that class.

Comment: I love this! It's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There exists `getElementsByClassName`; see [`document.getElementsByClassName` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery I suggest $('.classHere').

Comment: actually should be `'.classHere'` needs the . for class lookup

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change CSS values according to class name you can just use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

this will return you an array of all elements in whole document that have class which you search.

This will allow you to write a loop to change CSS for all of returned elements.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("theClassName");
document.querySelectorAll(".theClassName");
```

These methods won't work on older browsers (like IE7 or IE8). In this case you'll have to iterate through elements to check the class name, or rely on a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use jQuery, do the following:

---

function changeClassName(className, newClassName) {

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements; ++i) {
        var item = elements[i];  
        item.className = newClassName;
    }
```

}

---

If you decide to use jQuery:

function changeClassName(className, newClassName) {

```
    $('.'+className).toggleClass(newClassName);
```

}